# Window object appearing in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, window, raphael

When I run the code below, jQuery, repeatedly, puts a Window object in my array (and I'm sure the JSON doesn't include any references to the Window object).  Is there any way to run this and keep the Window object out of my array?

Thanks

```
$.getJSON("../php/return_network_data.php",
function(fetch_data){
    $.each(fetch_data, function(){
    var index = this.id;
    node_array[index] = paper.circle(this.xpos_init, this.ypos_init, 10).attr({"fill" : "#ff0000"})

    $.each(node_array, function(){
            console.log(this);
      });
  });
}
);
```

Comment: What makes you think jQuery is doing this, and not raphael or some other code? I'd look at the docs for your `paper.circle(...).attr(...)` to see if it can ever return `window`. If not, then look elsewhere in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work..have to add index,value in each function

```
$.getJSON("../php/return_network_data.php",
function(fetch_data){
    $.each(fetch_data, function(index,value){
    var index2 = value.id;
    node_array[index] = paper.circle(this.xpos_init, this.ypos_init, 10).attr({"fill" : "#ff0000"})

    $.each(node_array, function(index,value){
            console.log(value);
      });
  });
}
);
```

Comment: No, jQuery gives you the `value` via `this` as well, and so that's what OP seems to be using.

Comment: Is there any way to do this such that the index of my JS array is the ID of the JSON object?

Comment: @user1114864 ..well it depends on the way u make ur JSON object.,..surely u can make that...

Comment: @user1114864 Only if your id's start with 0 and don't have any missing indexes. Otherwise, it's going to have to be an array, either of values or objects/arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what paper.circle does exactly (is this raphael?), but I think it might be one of two things:

1. Removing the attr function from the paper command and adding it later.

   ```
   node_array[index] = paper.circle(this.xpos_init, this.ypos_init, 10);
   ```
2. Adding key, value to the function in each:

   ```
   $.getJSON("../php/return_network_data.php", function(fetch_data){
       $.each(fetch_data, function(key, value){
           var index = value.id;
           node_array[index] = paper.circle(value.xpos_init, value.ypos_init, 10).attr({"fill" : "#ff0000"})

           $.each(node_array, function(){
               console.log(this);
           });
       });
   });
   ```

Or possibly both?